# Please vote on whether to make [detective] a synonym of [mystery]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I see [detective](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/detective) and [mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery) used with a high degree of overlap. Namely, for puzzles which describe a scenario and then ask you to deduce the culprit or cause. To be fair, they do have differing wikis:

- Detective: "For puzzles that involve solving a crime."
- Mystery: "A puzzle that involves figuring out what happened with regards to a certain incident."

But in practice, almost any question tagged with one could be tagged with the other.

Based on the wiki descriptions, I propose that [detective](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/detective) should be made into a synonym of [mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery), as the wiki descriptions indicate that [detective](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/detective) is a proper subset of [mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery).

If you have an opinion and the ability to do so (it requires at least 1250 rep and a score of 5 in the tag), [please vote on the proposed synonym](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/mystery/synonyms).

Comment: I agree with this proposal, because it seems like even if there are distinct differences between [detective] and [mystery] questions, they aren't significant enough to warrant their own tag.

Comment: Yes, I have voted pro proposal as well.

Comment: I have also proposed a tag synonym that has gotten 0 votes which I don't understand...@Emrakul Do you agree with mine, or haven't seen it? http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/brainteaser/synonyms (Sorry for the hijacked thread but posting this would be a duplicate, not that it's really **that** bad lol)

Comment: @warspyking Because the tag synonym system could use some improvements. It's difficult to find the page; you have to be intentionally looking for it rather than just stumble upon it. And the requirements for voting are pretty high, at least for a beta site. When I edited this post to add the link, the mystery synonym was proposed but had no votes, even though this question got a reasonable amount of attention and upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this was done](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/mystery/synonyms) way back in 2014 by Joe Z.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Case closed, Sherlock.

Comment: (I'm mostly posting this answer in order to get the meta post off the Unanswered list and marked as solved.)