# Please vote on whether to make [logic] a synonym of [logic-puzzle]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I'm not sure if a meta question is an appropriate way to advertise my suggested synonymisation, but there is a [precedent](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/please-vote-on-whether-to-make-detective-a-synonym-of-mystery).

Surely it's obvious that the tags [logic] and [logic-puzzle] should be synonyms? They mean *exactly* the same in the context of this site.

You can vote on it [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/logic-puzzle/synonyms).

Comment: I agree with the merger but I can't vote for it. (not enough rep on "logic") ;c)

Comment: I agree too! In fact I was going to make the sunny in before I realized my rep total was too low. Probably from my previous puzzles that have failed... I really need to clean up my act. D;

Comment: @warspyking 'sunny in'?! Are you using a spell checker? ;-)

Comment: @rand Yep, iPod has it built in. synynom*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone ahead and manually approved the synonymization, so [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Thanks! The awesome power of mods...

Comment: Would you mind doing the same for [liars] and [knights-and-knaves]? Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, synonymized.

Comment: How about the brainteaser and lateral-thinking? Can you synonymize them too?

Comment: @warspyking Are you sure they should be synonyms? I thought they were slightly different from each other?

Comment: @rand read the descriptions :P

Comment: @rand al'thor Or go here; http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/what-exactly-is-the-point-of-lateral-thinking